# CPU cooler does not fit, will it cool worse if I cut tips of heatpipes off?

Tags: cooling, case, cpu-cooler

Case: zalman z9 neo 

Cooler: deepcool gammaxx 400

According to specs it should fit, but it does not, probably because my motherboard is mini-itx and cooler located a bit to the left

I'm thinking that cutting off those tips of heatpipes on the left would solve that; if I do that, will cooler work worse, like heatpipes would transfer heat not as good or something?

[image: does not fit[1]]

Comment: "Leak all the coolant out" would be my first thought :/

Comment: It's an air cooler, so there is no 'coolant' to leak out of. Thermal paste is only on the cooler contacts where the heatpipes meet the CPU, however I would say yes, it would be *very* detrimental to cut off the tips of those heatpipes.

Comment: Maybe we can word it differently. "Heat ransferingflued/gas" or whatever the exact stuff in the pipes is. Point is if the tips get cut then the stuff escaped and your cooling is ruined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Heat pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe) are a sealed tube in which liquid (contained inside the heat pipe) converts to vapour under heat, transferring the heat to the colder heat-sink end.  As which point it cools, condensates back to liquid, and returns to the hot end (at the CPU).

If you crack/puncture them, then they will cease to function, wrecking the CPU cooler.

Comment: Aha, so there IS something inside a heatpipe; the guy claims to hack-open the heatpipe and nothing was there: http://forumz.tomshardware.com/hardware/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=223830&highlight=heatpipes

Comment: Just to clarify: the heatpipes will still work by conduction, but their performance will be severely reduced.  It will probably be nearly useless for cooling a CPU, but will still conduct *some* heat.

Comment: @DannieP There may be some water vapour, but they will not be completely filled. On a first inspection it will seem mostly empty, then the coolant will evaporate making it *actually* empty.

Comment: @DannieP Of course there was something inside. :)
Don't expect anything to pour out. In a heat pipe you want the liquid to boil instantly when heat arrives, so it's way under room pressure (which means partial vacuum at room temperature).